# Java/Eclipse - Conditional breakpoint and counter?

Tags: java, eclipse, counter, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

Is it possible to have a condition on a breakpoint in Eclipse, and have the breakpoint "activate" after that condition has been met n times?

Say for example, in some sloppy mobile-written pseduocode, the breakpoint's condition is:

```
int n = 0;
If(i == j){
    n++
    If(n > 400)
        true;
}
```

With i and j being values in my class.

To please the duplicate-hunt, note that I am not asking *how* to use a conditional statement, I am asking how I can count the number of times a breakpoint condition is met, *then* have the breakpoint stop my code. Hit does not do this, nor does using a condition in any way I can figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To activate the breakpoint after the condition is met a certain number of times:

1. Open breakpoints dialog: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+double-click breakpoint**
2. **Check *Conditional* checkbox**
3. Use following as condition:

   ```
   if (i == j) {
       int n = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("breakpoint.n", "0"));
       n++;
       System.setProperty("breakpoint.n", "" + n);
       if (n > 400) return true;
   }
   return false;
   ```

Comment: I'm looking to have the breakpoint activate after the *condition* has been met a certain number of times. Hit is triggered everytime the breakpoint is reached, regardless of if the condition is met, and I want the condition to be met n times before the breakpoint works. Therefore, I do not want to use an outside variable variable in this case.

Comment: @Kal I changed the answer by including one more solution. I hope it's what you need.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question perfectly :)